# How can I make 2 divs of equal dimension using flexboxes?

Tags: html, css, web

One div has an img element, and the other has a background-image, with texts that I want to appear at the bottom of the text. But, in my code the second appears much smaller. Here's the pen:

```
codepen.io/tatai007/pen/xgYXZv
```

Comment: the image is  not loading

Comment: @CarolMcKay Which one?

Comment: the one that creates the height, the background image is loading I think.

Comment: I thought that too at first, but it's loading alright.

Comment: Please don't hide a link to a Pen in order to avoid posting relevant code in your question and bypass the script SO has put into place when you ask a question. It's there for a reason. Edit your question and paste your code, please